# Refresh ObservableCollection by changes on a remote server

Tags: wpf, gridview, observablecollection

I am fetching data from an URI and parseing the xml to populate my ObservableCollection<"classname"> and showing it on the GridView in my WPF project. The problem I am facing is, when i delete an entry from the ObservableCollection, event is triggered and GridView is updated. However if an entry is updated on the server from which i am getting the data from, no event is triggered on the ObservableCollection and list is not updated.

I have tried reloading the complete object list again on click event but still no changes can be viewed in the GridView. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: i have also tried reloading the list all over again and adding and removing a null object at index 0 to trigger changes but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

`ObservableCollection` only reports adding, removing or replacing items in it. It can't know anything about changes in the internal structure of the stored objects.

If you want changed in your objects reflected in the GUI, you should implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx).

Alternative approach would be to remove and then add back *the item that changed*, but it's not as clean as the previous solution.

Comment: i have also tried reloading the list all over again and adding and removing a null object at index 0 to trigger changes but still no luck .. any comments on that ?

Comment: its like this
Reload();
OpenTickets.Insert(0,crap);
OpenTickets.Remove(crap);

Comment: I'm not sure what `Reaload()` does, but and adding and removing empty item won't do anything. The collection will report exactly that and GUI won't have any reason to read the rest of the items again.

Comment: Reload is just a function that visits the URI gets the data parses it and inserts objects into the ObservableCollection ..